# NULL value is sent to Controller while updating datetime rendered using SetEditItemTemplateContent from GridView Editor Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, model-binding, devexpress-mvc

DevExpress 17.1

I am having a DateTime column in GridView which displays datetime as MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

I have used SetEditItemTemplateContent to have the DateEdit control in EditorForm for updating the DateTime field.

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "C_DateTime";
        column.Caption = "C_DateTime";
        column.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        column.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";

        column.SetEditItemTemplateContent(c =>
        {

            var workDate = (DateTime?)DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "C_DateTime");

            Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(
                dateEdit =>
                {
                    var keyValue = c.KeyValue == null? 0 : c.KeyValue;

                    dateEdit.Name = "C_DateTime" + keyValue.ToString();
                    dateEdit.Properties.UseMaskBehavior = true;
                    dateEdit.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
                    dateEdit.Properties.EditFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
                    dateEdit.Properties.TimeSectionProperties.Visible = true;
                    dateEdit.Properties.TimeSectionProperties.TimeEditProperties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
                    dateEdit.Properties.TimeSectionProperties.TimeEditProperties.EditFormatString = "hh:mm tt";
                    dateEdit.Date = DateTime.Now;
                }
                ).Bind(workDate).Render();
        });
    });
```

When I changed the datetime value in EditorForm and click Update button, NULL value is sent to the controller instead of the modified datetime value.

Please suggest a way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the editor's Name according to the bound Model's property:

```
Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(dateEdit => {
    //var keyValue = c.KeyValue == null? 0 : c.KeyValue;
    //dateEdit.Name = "C_DateTime" + keyValue.ToString();
    dateEdit.Name = "C_DateTime";
    ...
    //or
    dateEdit.Name = column.FieldName;
}).Bind(workDate).Render();
```

Note that you can add the necessary settings via the column.PropertiesEdit().DateEdit settings (without using the SetEditItemTemplateContent method).